# AngularJS 1.2.1 $injector:modulerr after minifying, yet it runs well before minification

Tags: angularjs

I have searched around. Some people come across this problem because they forgot to included certain modules, such as ngRoute or ngAnimate... I have included and injected them.

I am using Yeoman to bootstrap the project, and the app runs well before minification, that is running using "grunt server"

and after minifying (when I run "grunt server:dist"), I came across this problem:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…0(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fscripts%2Fd3a6bda4.vendor.js%3A1%3A11551) d3a6bda4.vendor.js:1`

Any idea on this? Thanks in advance.

---

@tschiela, thanks for suggesting me to take a look at the Gruntfile.js,  yet I think it should be fine, since I am using AngularJS (1.0.8) with my other projects too, and I use the same Gruntfile.js across projects.

@Gorgi Rankovski, thanks for suggesting me to take a look at my code,  here's some code, I am using CoffeeScript, I think I got what you mean,

```coffeescript

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$location'
    ($scope, $location) ->
        $scope.isSpecificPage = ->
            path = $location.path()
            return _.contains( ['/', '/index-vendor', '/404', '/signin', '/signup'], path )
])
```

```

Comment: A note on minification: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller_a-note-on-minification

Comment: @GorgiRankovski, thanks for your commend, yet I know I should inject the dependencies, and I remember my app ran well when using angular 1.0.8, even after minifying.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: please post your grunt task configuration

Comment: @GorgiRankovski, I have post some code, I am using CoffeeScript, I think I got what you mean, and I have injected the dependencies the Angular Way, I think that's not the problem here, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I get it work.

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I tried lots of things, at last, I found it *has something to do with the grunt-contrib-uglify task*.
(yet the same task works good when I using AngularJS 1.0.8, weird)

So, I didn't uglify the AngularJS files, instead, **I just do concat task**, removed the uglify step, now everything is fine.

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      steps: {
        'js': ['concat']
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: If this is an issue with uglify-js interfering with AngularJS, please post a bug report so that this can be resolved.

Comment: @KevinStone yeah, I guess uglify breaks AngularJS, yet I am not sure about that, since when I searching on the net, it seems it's only me who has encounter this problem.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue in my code base.  Ran fine with 1.2.0rc1, but 1.2.0rc3 and later seem to have this issue.  I minify with UglifyJS...

Comment: Did anyone find anything out about this? I get issues uglifying angular, particularly at the moment around the angular animate module

Answer (score 0):

That's kinda "normal" behavior. Angular is very sensitive to minification and you shouldn't do it by yourself. You should rather just prepend the Angular source to your built script. This was explained in a talk by Miško on Best practices. You can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY

Comment: Time stamp on the video would be nice